# Can someone tell me if there's anything wrong with this network configuration? + Multiple Public IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, switch, subnet

Firstly, is there anything wrong with this configuration? Secondly, will subnetting the network help with performance?
Also, my ISP provided **2 public IPs** through a single cable line. Will it be of any use to lower the network traffic? If I use a switch/hub and then distribute the line into two routers each with their unique public IP. Any help is highly appreciated.

**Note:** All users will be connecting to all the routers through **wifi**.

**The configuration**:

[image]

Comment: Your image is totally unclear. There is no difference between modem(s), router(s) and computers, and no difference between ethernet connection and wifi.

Comment: These are actually all routers connected to each other through LAN ports. I did not include any end device